# Interfacing 16x2 LCD to PIC 16F690

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, pic, lcd

I'm designing a digital incubator using a DHT-22 sensor and a 16x2 LCD. I programmed the pic to display my name and the title of my project before displaying the temperature and humidity, but I don't have the DHT-22 sensor yet.

In the simulation, when I disconnected the DHT-22 sensor, it displayed just my name and title and then blanked out but when I did the hardware connection it displayed gibberish. I used mikroC to code the project. I don't know if the fault is from my end or because I didn't connect the sensor.

[image: LCD connection]

```
#define bulb portb.f4
#define fan portb.f5
#define gear portb.f6
#define buzz portb.f7
// LCD module connections
sbit LCD_RS at RC2_bit;
sbit LCD_EN at RC3_bit;
sbit LCD_D4 at RC4_bit;
sbit LCD_D5 at RC5_bit;
sbit LCD_D6 at RC6_bit;
sbit LCD_D7 at RC7_bit;
sbit LCD_RS_Direction at TRISC2_bit;
sbit LCD_EN_Direction at TRISC3_bit;
sbit LCD_D4_Direction at TRISC4_bit;
sbit LCD_D5_Direction at TRISC5_bit;
sbit LCD_D6_Direction at TRISC6_bit;
sbit LCD_D7_Direction at TRISC7_bit;
// END of LCD initialization
char i;

// DHT22 pin connection (here data pin is connected to pin RB0)
#define DHT22_PIN         RA0_bit
#define DHT22_PIN_DIR     TRISA0_bit

#include <stdint.h>

// read one byte from sensor
uint8_t dht22_read_byte()
{
  uint8_t i = 8, dht22_byte = 0;

  while(i--)
  {
    while( !DHT22_PIN );

    Delay_us(40);

    if( DHT22_PIN )
    {
      dht22_byte |= (1 << i);   // set bit i
      while( DHT22_PIN );
    }
  }
  return(dht22_byte);
}

// read humidity (in hundredths rH%) and temperature (in hundredths °Celsius) from sensor
void dht22_read(uint16_t *dht22_humi, int16_t *dht22_temp)
{
  // send start signal
  DHT22_PIN     = 0;   // connection pin output low
  DHT22_PIN_DIR = 0;   // configure connection pin as output
  Delay_ms(25);        // wait 25 ms
  DHT22_PIN     = 1;   // connection pin output high
  Delay_us(30);        // wait 30 us
  DHT22_PIN_DIR = 1;   // configure connection pin as input

  // check sensor response
  while( DHT22_PIN );
  while(!DHT22_PIN );
  while( DHT22_PIN );

  // read data
  *dht22_humi = dht22_read_byte();  // read humidity byte 1
  *dht22_humi = (*dht22_humi << 8) | dht22_read_byte();  // read humidity byte 2
  *dht22_temp = dht22_read_byte();  // read temperature byte 1
  *dht22_temp = (*dht22_temp << 8) | dht22_read_byte();  // read temperature byte 2
  dht22_read_byte();               // read checksum (skipped)

  if(*dht22_temp & 0x8000)// if temperature is negative
  {
    *dht22_temp &= 0x7FFF;
    *dht22_temp *= -1;
  }
}

char message[] = "00.0";
int humidity, temperature;

void Move_Delay() {                  // Function used for text moving
  Delay_ms(400);                     // You can change the moving speed here
}

// main function
void main()
{
  PORTB = 0X00;
  TRISB = 0X00;
  //added the above
  PORTC = 0X00;
  TRISC = 0X40;
  ADCON1 = 0x00;//ADC Off
  ADCON0 = 0x00;
  ansel = 0x00;
  anselh = 0x00;
  CM1CON0 = 0x00;//comparator 1 off
  CM2CON0 = 0X00; //comparator 2 off
  Lcd_Init();
  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CURSOR_OFF);
  Lcd_Out(1,1,"Unamma Chukwunonso");
  Lcd_Out(2,1,"Digital Egg Incubator");
  Delay_ms(1000);

  for(i=0; i<5; i++) {               // Move text to the right 6 times
    Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_SHIFT_LEFT);
    Move_Delay();
  }

  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);

  while(1)
  {

    dht22_read(&humidity, &temperature);

    Lcd_Out(1,1,"HUMIDITY:");
    Lcd_Out(2,1,"TEMP:");

    message[0] = humidity/100 + 48;
    message[2] = humidity/10%10 + 48;
    message[3] = humidity%10 + 48;
    Lcd_Out(1,11, message);
    Lcd_Out(1,16,"%");

    message[0] = temperature/100 + 48;
    message[2] = temperature/10%10 + 48;
    message[3] = temperature%10 + 48;
    Lcd_Out(2,11, message);
    Lcd_Chr_CP(223);
    Lcd_Out(2,16,"C");

    Delay_ms(1000);  // wait a second

if(temperature < 375) {
  bulb = 1;
  fan = 1;
  buzz = 1;
 }
 else if(temperature > 380) {
  bulb = 0;
  fan = 1;
  buzz = 0;
 }
 else if(temperature >= 375 && temperature <= 380) {
  bulb = 1;
  buzz = 0;
  }
  if(temperature > 383) {
  buzz = 1;
  }
}}
```

Comment: Are you sure the hardware connection is correct?

Comment: thanks, that was the problem. I've rectified the connections.

Answer (score 1):

I made a mistake in the hardware connection from the MCU to the LCD.

Comment: Exactly what mistake did you make? (I'm curious to know how the LCD could display text in the simulation even though the connections were wrong).

Comment: This site is meant to show helpful answers to questions, so that they help others with similar problems. So, please, explain in detail the mistake you made.

Comment: Antoine - Hi, When I encouraged you to write an answer earlier, as mentioned in the comments above, I meant it should contain enough detail to help readers in the future e.g. to help them identify what mistake was causing their problem. Is you answer trying to say that your simulation was correct, and you just mis-wired the actual hardware? If so, do you remember *how* the hardware wiring was incorrect? Or are you saying that the simulation wiring is wrong, and it worked in the simulation but not on actual hardware? You can [Edit] your answer to add more detail. Thanks!